# How to merge days with similar opening hours

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a javascript function to merge days with similar opening hours of a store together. For example, if we have:

"hours": [
"Friday 11:00am - 3:00pm, 5:00pm - 10:00pm",
"Monday 11:00am - 3:00pm, 5:00pm - 9:30pm",
"Saturday 12:00pm - 10:00pm",
"Sunday 12:00pm - 9:30pm",
"Thursday 11:00am - 3:00pm, 5:00pm - 9:30pm",
"Tuesday 11:00am - 3:00pm, 5:00pm - 9:30pm",
"Wednesday 11:00am - 3:00pm, 5:00pm - 9:30pm"
],

I want the code to simplify it to:

"hours": [
"Mo-Sa 11:00-14:30",
"Mo-Th 17:00-21:30",
"Fr-Sa 17:00-22:00"
],

Is there a way of accomplishing this without a long list of `if/else` or `case` statements?

Comment: What is your data structure like?  If you make an attempt at coding, even if it is wrong/doesn't work, that would greatly help in being able to answer the question correctly.

Comment: Is it always gonna be the same Mon-Fri and Sat-Sun?

Comment: just replace each day that has the same day as last time with nothing, unless it's the last match.

Comment: It is in thew above format, I just need to group in

Comment: So you're saying your data structure is a string in your JavaScript?

Comment: var data =[
"Mon: 11:00 AM to 10:30 PM",
"Sat: 11:00 AM to 10:00 PM",
"Thu: 11:00 AM to 10:30 PM",
"Tue: 11:00 AM to 10:30 PM",
"Wed: 11:00 AM to 10:32 PM",
"Fri: 11:00 AM to 10:00 PM",
"Sun: 11:00 AM to 10:30 PM",
];     This is the array I have

Comment: I've edited the title of the question to focus on the problem rather than javascript in particular, since javascript already. I've also fixed the sample data formatting, since markdown will just concatenate multiple lines into a single block if they aren't prefixed by 4 spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go functional and save a lot of mess.

Assuming that this is your data:

```
var data = [
    {day: "Mon", open: 900, close: 1700},
    {day: "Tue", open: 900, close: 1700},
    {day: "Wed", open: 700, close: 1700},
    {day: "Thu", open: 900, close: 1700},
    {day: "Fri", open: 900, close: 1700},
    {day: "Sat", open: 900, close: 1900},
    {day: "Sun", open: 900, close: 1900},
];
```

You can simply `reduce` the array to a merged array in 6 lines of code:

```
var merged = data.reduce(function(preVal, curVal) {
    var last = preVal[preVal.length - 1];
    if (last && last.open == curVal.open && last.close == curVal.close) {
        last.endDay = curVal.day;
    } else {
        preVal.push(curVal);
    }
    return preVal;
}, []);
```

And just in case for debugging:

```
for (var i in merged) {
    var m = merged[i];
    var endDay = m.endDay ? " to " + m.endDay : "";
    console.log(m.day + endDay + " " + m.open + "-" + m.close);
}
```

**BONUS** Now, if you have to convert `merged` into a different format (e.g., something that you need to print on the screen) you can go functional again and `map` the merged into whatever format you want:

```
var mergedNewFormat = merged.map(function(v) { 
   return {
      days: [v.day, v.endDay ? v.endDay : v.day],
      hours: [v.open, v.close],
   };
});
```

Comment: Might want to include a function that converts the final structure (day, open, close, endDay) into the required format.  Nice solution though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it does not work properly. When timings are not the same in sequence.  eg: {day: "Mon", open: 900, close: 1700},
    {day: "Tue", open: 1000, close: 1700},
    {day: "Wed", open: 900, close: 1700},

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest breaking your data down into a more structured format than what you currently have specified in your comments such as:

```
var data = [
  { day: "Mon", hours: "11:00 AM to 10:30 PM" },
  { day: "Thu", hours: "11:00 AM to 10:30 PM" },
  { day: "Tue", hours: "11:00 AM to 10:30 PM" },
  { day: "Wed", hours: "11:00 AM to 10:32 PM" },
  { day: "Fri", hours: "11:00 AM to 10:00 PM" },
  { day: "Sat", hours: "11:00 AM to 10:00 PM" },
  { day: "Sun", hours: "11:00 AM to 10:30 PM" }
];
```

Now you can iterate over the days and group by identical hours like this:

```
function collapseHours(data) {
  var collapsed = [];
  var idx = -1;
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var day = data[i];
    if(idx == -1 || collapsed[idx].hours != day.hours) {
      collapsed.push({days:[day.day],hours:day.hours});
      idx++;
    } else {
      collapsed[idx].days.push(day.day);
    }
  }
  return collapsed;
}
```

This `collapseHours(data)` would produce the following:

```
[
  {"days":["Mon","Thu","Tue"],"hours":"11:00 AM to 10:30 PM"},
  {"days":["Wed"],"hours":"11:00 AM to 10:32 PM"},
  {"days":["Fri","Sat"],"hours":"11:00 AM to 10:00 PM"},
  {"days":["Sun"],"hours":"11:00 AM to 10:30 PM"}
];
```

Now you can pretty print your hours like this:

```
function prettyPrintHours(collapsed) {
   var lines = [];
   for(var i=0; i<collapsed.length; i++) {
     var line = collapsed[i];
     var days = line.days;
     if(days.length == 1) {
       lines.push(days[0]+" "+line.hours);
     } else {
       lines.push(days[0]+"-"+days[days.length-1]+" "+line.hours);
     }
   }
   return lines;
}
```

Which will produce:

```
[
 "Mon-Tue 11:00 AM to 10:30 PM",
 "Wed 11:00 AM to 10:32 PM",
 "Fri-Sat 11:00 AM to 10:00 PM",
 "Sun 11:00 AM to 10:30 PM"
]
```

Given these two functions it should be relatively simple to customize the data format and output formatting to your exact needs.

Comment: This is a pretty nice solution. But in my case I need to collapse this data { day: 0, from: "09:00", to: "12:00" }. I do not have hours in a single string :( Could you please suggest anything? Thank you.